# I would like to learn more about VT-d (IOMMU) technology, where should I start?

Tags: virtualization, intel, iommu

I'm a low-level enthuatist, I love Intel VT-x and recently had some spare time to read and enjoy. I recently got into the term VT-d which allows to create "device realms" per device, and I would like to learn more about it, however when searching in [1] [2] .
Didn't Intel publish documentation regarding this technology ? and if so - where ?

I don't want to read Xen src (although this is an option), I would like to read the actual documentation that Intel published regarding this matter.

Perhaps you guys could assist here.

[1] http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/252046.pdf
[2] http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't read the right documents. Intel has the VT-d spec [here](http://download.intel.com/technology/computing/vptech/Intel%28r%29_VT_for_Direct_IO.pdf) (pdf). If you need to see the code you can find Linux drivers [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/drivers/iommu/).